# File Not found Exception in Android file Picker in Nougat While it Works fine in Kitkat

Tags: java, android, filenotfoundexception, file-not-found, android-fileprovider

The code below works fine in api level 19 and the path displays as **/storage/0/download/w.xls**
While it gives the error in api level 26.

Please give some suggestion, how do i resolve it?

> `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/primary:Download/W.xls (No such file or directory)`

```
public void getdata(String filestring){
    try{
        File file = new File(filestring);
        Workbook w;
        w = Workbook.getWorkbook(file);
        Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
        for (int j = 1; j<sheet.getRows(); j++){

            Cell c1 = sheet.getCell(0,j);
            Cell c2 = sheet.getCell(1,j);

            String date =  c1.getContents();
            String empid = c2.getContents();
adb.insertRoastData(date,empid,project,name,route,cabno,location,contact,gender,duty,shift,cabtype,zone);
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
public void performFileSearch() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                             Intent resultData) {
    if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = null;
        if (resultData != null) {
            uri = resultData.getData();
            String filepath = getPath(uri);
            getdata(filepath);
        }
    }
}
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String path = null;
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if(cursor == null){
        path = uri.getPath();
    }
    else{
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(projection[0]);
        path = cursor.getString(column_index);
        cursor.close();
    }
    return ((path == null || path.isEmpty()) ? (uri.getPath()) : path);
}
```

Comment: Do you have the necessary storage permission and have you requested it in the runtime?

Comment: You got a non existing path. Dont you see.? Dont try to convert a content scheme to a file path. Just use the content schem itself.

Comment: `w = Workbook.getWorkbook(file);`. You create a Workbook by indicating a File object. Is there a possibility to indicate an InputStream instead?

Comment: @NabinBhandari Yes i have requested at runtime and allowed the permission.

Comment: Have a look at uri.toSfring(). That is your content scheme.

Comment: No i need the file path as i am inserting the data from excel sheet to the database @greenapps

Comment: Please answer my question about Workbook.

Comment: No @greenapps , i want the filepath in the workbook for importing the file to the database

Comment: That is no answer to my question. I did not ask what you want. I asked if something was possible.

Comment: I didn't tried it with inputstream yet @greenapps

Comment: You do not have to try it by running your app. The compiler will tell you if you can use an input stream there.

Comment: I don't know how that can be done please tell @greenapps

Comment: Find out if you can code something like InputStream is = null; w = Workbook.getWorkbook(is):. Does the compiler accept that? Or is there another call to create a Workbook from an InputStream instead of from a File?

Comment: Okay, after trying this i will let you know @greenapps

Answer (score 0):

> The code below works fine in api level 19

No, it does not. There is no requirement for the `Uri` that is returned by `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` to be from the `MediaStore`. Moreover, the `Uri` returned by `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` does not have to represent a file on the local filesystem, let alone one that you are authorized to access.

Use a `ContentResolver` (obtained by calling `getContentResolver()` on a `Context`, such as your `Activity`) and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`.

Comment: I have tried that too but that also not working @CommonsWare

Comment: @user6698813: Nobody can help you if you do not explain what "not working" means.

Comment: @user6698813: [Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.7/Documents/Durable) that uses `openInputStream()`. [Here is another](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.7/Documents/TinyTextEditor). [Here is a third](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.7/Documents/Diceware). All involve `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. All are covered in a chapter of [this book](https://commonsware.com/Android/). [Here is a preview edition of that chapter](https://commonsware.com/Android/previews/consuming-documents).

Comment: Hey @CommonsWare thanks for the help. but can you please tell me how should i use these files as they are showing errors import com.commonsware.cwac.document.DocumentFileCompat;
        import org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus;

Comment: @user6698813: Those are from libraries, declared in the `dependencies` closure in `app/build.gradle`. `DocumentFileCompat` is from [this library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-document). greenrobot's EventBus has [a GitHub repo too](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

Answer (score -2):

Try this code for get path

```
/**
 * Get a file path from a Uri. This will get the the path for Storage Access
 * Framework Documents, as well as the _data field for the MediaStore and
 * other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context The context.
 * @param uri The Uri to query.
 * @author paulburke
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }

            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {

        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Get the value of the data column for this Uri. This is useful for
 * MediaStore Uris, and other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context The context.
 * @param uri The Uri to query.
 * @param selection (Optional) Filter used in the query.
 * @param selectionArgs (Optional) Selection arguments used in the query.
 * @return The value of the _data column, which is typically a file path.
 */
public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                   String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}


/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
 */
public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```

Comment: Its gives the error --  jxl.read.biff.BiffException: Unable to recognize OLE stream